# Shared elements animation with AppCompat inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, transition, material-design

I have a Fragment with some ImageViews, if I click on one of this ImageViews the app open a new activity where the just clicked "target" image is at the top of it.

In the first place I put the ImageView in the new Activity directly in the parent layout.

Now in this activity I've set a custom Header as the first item of the RecyclerView, the "target" ImageView is in this new header.

Now the transition doesn't work anymore. I've thought that the content of the RecyclerView is drawn later, so I've tryed with

```
        ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this);
```

before setContentView (I dont know if it's correct)
and

```
        ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(mContext);
```

in onBindViewHolder of the RecyclerView.

But it doesn't work...what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by using

```
        setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
            sharedElements.put("profile_user_img", image);
            super.onMapSharedElements(names, sharedElements);
        }
    });
```

in conjunction with postponeEnterTransition and startPostponedEnterTransition

Comment: Did you put this after `postponeEnterTransition()` or `startPostponedEnterTransition()` ? I think I have the same issue.

Comment: 1)getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
2)postponeEnterTransition
3)super.onCreate
4)setContentView
5)setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
6)setEnterSharedElementCallback(...)

...

startPostponedEnterTransition